# in cmake, can cmake folder and CMakeLists.txt sit in different folder?

Tags: c++, c, build, cmake, build-process

in cmake, can cmake folder and CMakeLists.txt sit in different folder?\

usually, cmake folder and CmakeLists.txt are in same source root directory.
But, to re-use cmake folder for different project, is that possible to put cmake folder into other places?

Is this a good approach ans thinking?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean with "cmake folder?"

Comment: "cmake"  folder which includes "Modules" folder and others .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with that. You just have to know the relative path from the ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} or the absolute path in order to use it in your CMake files.